# Django forms with odd model relationship

Tags: django, django-forms

I am working with an existing database that I can not modify and having some trouble trying to deal with presenting forms for modifying the database in Django. The structure in question is as follows and all models are unmanaged.

```
class Persons(models.Model):
    personid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='PersonID') 
    ....

class Phones(models.Model):
    phoneid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='PhoneID') 
    number = models.CharField(max_length=60, db_column='Number', blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, db_column='Type', blank=True)
    ...

class Personsphones(models.Model):
    personphoneid = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='PersonPhoneID')
    personid = models.ForeignKey(Persons, db_column='PersonID') 
    phoneid = models.ForeignKey(Phones, db_column='PhoneID')
    ...
```

I want to create a form to display all of the 'Phones' associated with a particular 'Persons' and in addition be able to modify/add/remove 'Phones' belonging to a 'Persons'. Right now the only thing I can think of is to display the 'Phones' in a modelformset and then if one is added or removed manually set the 'Personsphones' relation. Any ideas on how to best deal with this model setup?

Answer (score 0):

For making changes to your models you may want to use django-south http://south.aeracode.org/docs/ 
As far as displaying your 'Phone' under your forms.py you may want to set up class meta like so. With this any changes made to models will reflect on change

```
class Meta:
    model = Persons
    exclude = ('user')
```

In models you may want to use Foreignkey fore relationships between phones and Persons. Better seen in action here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Thanks but perhaps I wasn't clear in my meaning of unable to modify the database. I meant that the database schema must not change due to factors outside of my control. If I was able to have a foreign key between Phones and Persons I would not have a problem.